# uninitialized constant when calling class method in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a class called Device. It has a model device.rb

I have set the routing up so that the same  controller is called from two different paths. i.e. the paths:

```
/driver_api/v1/devices
```

and

```
/sender_api/v1/devices
```

both call the following controller:

```
/user_api/v1/devices
```

In my routes.rb I have:

```
namespace :driver_api do
  namespace :v1 do
     resources :devices, :only => [:create], controller: '/user_api/v1/devices'
  end
end

namespace :sender_api do
  namespace :v1 do
     resources :devices, :only => [:create], controller: '/user_api/v1/devices'
  end
end
```

Now, in my devices controller, I'm trying to call a Device class method. i.e. in my controller:

```
class UserApi::V1::DevicesController < ApplicationController

      Devise.method_name(input)
end
```

But i get an error:

```
uninitialized constant UserApi::V1::DevicesController::Device
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: try `::Devise.method_name(input)`

Comment: Device or Devise ? Your example uses both

Answer (score 1):

Because you wrote `Devise` and not `Device` that could be a good reason.

If that is just a typpo from the question, here's another alternative.
Sometimes there's some kind of naming problem when the classes are defined in the way you did (I ignore the reason why that happens)

Try to decompose the class scoping by defining the modules:

```
module UserApi
  module V1
    class DevicesController < ApplicationController
      # rest
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. yep that was a typo. question should have read 'device' not 'devise'. Actually after two hours of trying to get this to work, simply resetting the server did the job. However, this is a really useful alternative nomenclature that I wasn't aware of. So very helpful. thanks anyway.